# Creating a unique composite key, where one of its components is a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I'm using Postgres, and I'm trying to model a scoreboard app (say, where a single person is keeping track of scores for a board game).

As an example, Alice is a user on the app that wants to tally scores for herself and her friends Bob, Caden and David. None of her friends are users, but they don't need to make an account in order for Alice to add them to a scoreboard.

Later on, Caden is impressed with the app and decides to make an account. Alice then is able to link the Caden she added to her scoreboard to Caden's actual account on the app.

So I define a **user** as someone with an account. And a **player** as a "temporary" account that can later be linked to a user. A user can moderate players by adding them to a scoreboard. Here's my initial schema:

### users

| user_id | username | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | alice | alice@email.com |
| u2 | caden | caden@email.com |

### players

| player_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | Alice |
| p2 | Bob |
| p3 | Caden |
| p4 | David |

### players_to_moderated_by

| player_id | moderated_by (foreign key to users) |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | u1 |
| p2 | u1 |
| p3 | u1 |
| p4 | u1 |

### players_to_linked_to

| player_id | linked_to (foreign key to users) |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | u1 |
| p3 | u2 |

Now, I want to make two unique constraints

- `moderated_by` and `players.name` so that a user cannot confusingly add two players with the same exact name on a scoreboard
- `moderated_by` and `linked_to` so that a user cannot add two players that happen to be linked to the same user

However, in both cases the two components are keys/columns in separate tables. How do I define these constaints in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have too many tables. Gather all data about a player in a single table. Example:

```sql
create table players(
    id int generated always as identity primary key,
    player_name text,
    moderated_by int references users,
    linked_to int references users
);
```

As `linked_to` may be `null` you need a partial unique index (that cannot be explicitly defined as a table constraint):

```sql
create unique index on players(player_name, moderated_by);
create unique index on players(moderated_by, linked_to) where linked_to is not null;
```

Comment: Since I’m in the initial stages, I wanted to keep the data as normalized as possible (i.e. to not have two many-to-many relationships in one table). Although, the solution to the `linked_to` possibly being `null` was helpful since it the main problem I was running into.

Comment: There are no many-to-many relations in the table. A player has exactly one moderator and no more than one account.

Comment: Ah, right. I don't know what I thought so